# Tailwind css flex overflow-x w-1/4 not working

Tags: tailwind-css

How to make flex overflow-x in tailwind css when there i have 5 divs with w-1/4?

```
<div class"flex overflow-auto w-full relative">
  <div class="w-1/4"> sample </div>
  <div class="w-1/4"> sample </div>
  <div class="w-1/4"> sample </div>
  <div class="w-1/4"> sample </div>
  <div class="w-1/4"> sample </div>
</div>
```

What I'm expecting is that the fifth div will overflow but flex still displays the fifth div. How can i make it overflow the fifth div?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you trying to do. Do you want to put the fifth div into a new line with flex: wrap?
Otherwise flex because it will try to squeeze in all the divs.

overflow-auto makes a vertical scrollbar but you have to limit the parent height.

Comment: no, i want it to overflow so i can scroll but instead all the divs resizes to fit in the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `flex-none` on the inner divs

---

**Old answer:**

With TailwindJIT, use a min-width: `min-w-[25%]` or add your own scale in the `tailwind.config.js` as described [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/min-width#min-width-scale), for example:

```
module.exports = {
    theme: {
        minWidth: {
            '1/4': '25%',
        }
    }
}
```

And then use `min-w-1/4`.